# UIView is not showing except for a button action in swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

[image]I have created a UI in storyboard which has top, center, and bottom UIViews.

Below the bottom screen there is another UIView  which will show only for a button action in bottom, this comes as .CurveLinear from bottom to top ,

This works perfectly fine for a button action, but I want to happen this for a viewDidAppear, but its not working:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.1, options: .CurveLinear , animations: {
    self.infoView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, self.infoView.frame.size.width, self.infoView.frame.size.height)
    }) { (true) in

}
```

This is the code block that I execute to bring the view from bottom to top, how come it only works for a button action?

Comment: When are you calling it in viewDidAppear? When do you create the infoView?

Comment: its already been created in storyboard  , im doing the transition

Comment: are you using constraints in the storyboard?

Comment: Yes i do  , but all this wil work for a button action in bottom  right corner

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue , this animation didn't work until i use NSTimer , i think i had to wait until the view renders properly , but viewDidAppear executes after the view renders , so too many unanswered questions

Comment: Can you post your viewDidAppear code in the question?